# Preconfigured development environment image

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, deployment, lamp

I am looking for a way to package together a developer environment within ubuntu.  What I mean by this is that I need to be able to install ubuntu preconfigured with lamp (including the database entries needed by our developers), nodsjs, preconfigured eclipse, etc.  I need to be able to custom tailor the deployment for my companies development needs.  Does anyone know of any guides/programs/etc to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at something like [Chef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef_%28software%29) or [Puppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29).

Comment: +1 - I use Chef together with [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) to to preconfigured development environment VMs, and I like Chef quite a bit.